# Group by date-part (dd.mm.yyyy)

Tags: c#, json, linq

I've got a list of objects with a datetime-property. I struggle in getting a Json-string in the following form of it:

```
        [{"Date":17.08.2013,"Count":8},{"Day":18.08.2013,"Count":10}]
```

This

```
        var results = from a in db.Stalkings
                      group a by new { d = a.Begin.Day }
                      into g
                      select new { Day = g.Key.d, Count = g.Count() };
        return Json( results, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

results in [{"Day":17,"Count":8},{"Day":18,"Count":10}]. And this

```
        var results1 = from a in db.Stalkings
                       group a by EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(a.Begin)
                       into g
                       select new { Day = g.Key, Count = g.Count() };
         return Json( results, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

results in [{"Day":"/Date(1376690400000)/","Count":8},{"Day":"/Date(1376776800000)/","Count":10}]

DateTime.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy") leads to a linq error.

Comment: That is invalid JSON.

Comment: Hint: Use `DateTime.ToString`

Comment: Do you want to group by day or date?

Comment: I do not have visual studio at hand but in the first solution try d= format(a.Begin) where format is a function that you will write that takes in the date object and returns the correctly formatted date as a string. Date formatting is quite easy. Just google it.

Comment: like leppie said, on yout DateTime object use .ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
I thinks it's the proper formatting.

Comment: @Hamlet, I want to group by date ( dd.MM.yyyy ). Unfortunatly, using .ToString("dd.MM.yyyy") in the linq expression gives me "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Comment: The counts after the big numbers are correct.. I suppose the string formatting goes wrong and the order by works correctly. Could be ticks..

Comment: Why not use `group a by a.Begin`?

Comment: It's ticks .. but I need them formatted as dd.MM.yyyy :o/

Comment: @Hamlet, that's what I tried first .. group a by a.Begin gives [{"Day":"\/Date(1376690400000)\/","Count":8},{"Day":"\/Date(1376776800000)\/","Count":10}]

Answer (score 1):

I did a quick scratchup in [Linqpad.](http://www.linqpad.net)

I made an extension class and added the extension methods provided [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/EltonStoneman/archive/2012/05/11/extension-method-for-outputting-formatted-json-in-linqpad.aspx). You cannot use DumpJson() outside of Linqpad, it is however only a visualisation of data.

For the sake of simplicity I used just a list of DateTime Values. Here is the code which wil provide the following output:

```
void Main()
{
    var FooList = new List<DateTime>();

    FooList.Add(DateTime.Parse("01.01.2012"));
    FooList.Add(DateTime.Parse("01.01.2012"));
    FooList.Add(DateTime.Parse("01.01.2012"));
    FooList.Add(DateTime.Parse("03.03.2012"));
    FooList.Add(DateTime.Parse("04.04.2012"));
    FooList.Add(DateTime.Parse("04.04.2012"));
    FooList.Add(DateTime.Parse("04.04.2012"));
    FooList.Add(DateTime.Parse("04.04.2012"));
    FooList.Add(DateTime.Parse("05.05.2012"));
    FooList.Add(DateTime.Parse("05.05.2012"));


    var result = FooList.GroupBy(foo => foo.Date)
                        .Select(res => new 
                            {
                                date = res.Key.DateToString("dd.MM.yyyy"), 
                                Count = res.Count()
                            })  ;
    result.DumpJson();
}

public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static object DumpJson(this object value, string description = null)
       {
              return GetJsonDumpTarget(value).Dump(description);
       }    

       public static object DumpJson(this object value, string description, int depth)
       {
              return GetJsonDumpTarget(value).Dump(description, depth);
       }    

       public static object DumpJson(this object value, string description, bool toDataGrid)
       {
              return GetJsonDumpTarget(value).Dump(description, toDataGrid);
       }    

       private static object GetJsonDumpTarget(object value)
       {
              object dumpTarget = value;
              //if this is a string that contains a JSON object, do a round-trip serialization to format it:
              var stringValue = value as string;
              if (stringValue != null)
              {
                     if (stringValue.Trim().StartsWith("{"))
                     {
                           var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(stringValue);
                           dumpTarget = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
                     }
                     else
                     {
                           dumpTarget = stringValue;
                     }
              }
              else
              {
                     dumpTarget = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
              }
              return dumpTarget;
       }

}
```

> Output:

```
[
  {
    "date": "2012-01-01T00:00:00",
    "Count": 3
  },
  {
    "date": "2012-03-03T00:00:00",
    "Count": 1
  },
  {
    "date": "2012-04-04T00:00:00",
    "Count": 4
  },
  {
    "date": "2012-05-05T00:00:00",
    "Count": 2
  }
]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort, it looks like this is what I need though I find it strange that there seems to be no simpler / shorter way.

Comment: I needed to use these extension methods, because Linqpad has no out of the box way to parse results into JSON. My suggestion would be to return them and then use serialisation to parse them into Json after the query. I think the problem is your grouping statement. 
In the first one you get the month of the day as a result and in the second you get ticks(?)
Try using my Grouping. It should do the trick for you